# Aurora PostgreSQL permissions to access s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, amazon-aurora

Im trying to give my Aurora PostgreSQL permissions to access an s3 bucket. I'm using the serverless framework and have the following code.

```
 RDSCluster:
      Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBCluster'
      Properties:
        MasterUsername: AuserName
        MasterUserPassword: Apassword
        DBSubnetGroupName: 
          Ref: RDSClusterGroup
        AvailabilityZones: 
        - eu-central-1a
        - eu-central-1b
        Engine: aurora-postgresql
        EngineVersion: 11.9
        EngineMode: provisioned
        EnableHttpEndpoint: true
        DatabaseName: initialbase
        DBClusterParameterGroupName:
          Ref: RDSDBParameterGroup
        AssociatedRoles:
          - RoleArn:
              { Fn::GetAtt: [ AuroraPolicy, Arn ] }
        VpcSecurityGroupIds:
          - Ref: RdsSecurityGroup

    AuroraPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - rds.amazonaws.com
            Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
        Path: "/"
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: AuroraRolePolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:AbortMultipartUpload
                  - s3:GetBucketLocation
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:ListBucket
                  - s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource:
                  -  { Fn::GetAtt: [ S3BucketEgresbucket, Arn ] }
                  - Fn::Join:
                    - ""
                    - -  { Fn::GetAtt: [ S3BucketEgresbucket, Arn ] }
                      - "/*"
```

This should grant the DB permission to execute query's using `SELECT aws_commons.create_s3_ur`

However when I try and deploy I get the error message:

**The feature-name parameter must be provided with the current operation for the Aurora (PostgreSQL) engine.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the AssociatedRoles object, cloudformation states that the FeatureName field is not needed however if you are wishing for your cluster to access other AWS services it is required. In this case as I was wanting to have my cluster access an s3 bucket I had to change my AssociatedRoles object so it looked like this:

```
AssociatedRoles:
        - RoleArn: { Fn::GetAtt: [ roleServiceIntegration, Arn ] }
          FeatureName: s3Import
```